# quadtree update object failed

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a problem when implement quadtree
When an object in Quadtree move, we must update position of that object in Quadtree.
I try to code an update function by myself but it doesn't work.***(void UpdatePosition(QuadNode *root,bool& OK))***

My Quadtree class below:

```
class QuadNode
    {
    public:
        vector<Object*> listObj;

        RECT*       _rect;
        QuadNode*   LT,*RT,*LB,*RB;
        QuadNode()
        {
            _rect=NULL;
            LT=RT=LB=RB=NULL;
        }
        QuadNode(int left,int top,int width,int height)
        {
            _rect=new RECT();
            _rect->left=left;
            _rect->top=top;
            _rect->right=_rect->left+width;
            _rect->bottom=_rect->top+height;
            LT=RT=LB=RB=NULL;
        }
    };

    class QuadTree
    {
    public:
        bool CheckRECTInRECT(RECT r,RECT rect);
        bool CheckPointInRECT(int x,int y,RECT rect);
        void GetObjInRec(QuadNode* root,RECT Screen,vector<Object*> &result);

        QuadNode*   _pRoot;
        int         _mapWidth;
        int         _mapHeight;
        int         _count;

        QuadTree(int w,int h);
        ~QuadTree(void);

        void Add(QuadNode *root,Object *Ob);
        void OutPutTree(QuadNode *root);
        QuadNode* getTreeRoot(){ return _pRoot; };
        //Chi in nhung cai nam tren main hinh hien tai
        void DrawObjects(RECT Screen);
        Object* CheckCollision(QuadNode *root,RECT r,int Seq);
        void CheckCollision(QuadNode *root,RECT r,vector<Object*>&result);
        bool IsOnObject(RECT *rect,int Seq);//duoi chan object la object khac hay la khoang trong
        void UpdatePosition(QuadNode *root,bool& OK);
        void GetAllObj(QuadNode *root,vector<Object*> &result);
        void RemoveAll(QuadNode *root);
    };
```

and:

```
QuadTree::QuadTree(int w,int h)
    {
        _mapWidth=w;
        _mapHeight=h;
        _pRoot=new QuadNode(0,0,_mapWidth,_mapHeight);
        //_count=0;
    }
    void QuadTree::Add(QuadNode *root,Object *Ob)
    {   
        if(root!=NULL)
        {
            //0: Add ....1: Left_Top..... 2: Right_Top....... 3: Left_Bottom...... 4: Right_Bottom
            int result=0;//add here

            int objWidth    =   Ob->getObjectRect().right - Ob->getObjectRect().left;
            int objHeight   =   Ob->getObjectRect().bottom - Ob->getObjectRect().top;

            int rectWidth   =   root->_rect->right - root->_rect->left; 
            int rectHeight  =   root->_rect->bottom - root->_rect->top;

            int rectWidthNew=   (root->_rect->right + root->_rect->left)/2; //divide RECT root to quad RECT
            int rectHeightNew=  (root->_rect->bottom + root->_rect->top)/2;

            if((objWidth*objHeight > rectWidth*rectHeight/4)/*kiem tra dien tich co lon hon 1/4 dien tich roof ko*/ 
                || (rectWidthNew > Ob->getObjectRect().left && rectWidthNew <= Ob->getObjectRect().right)||
                (rectHeightNew > Ob->getObjectRect().top && rectHeightNew <= Ob->getObjectRect().bottom))
                result=0;//Kiem tra xem objet nam o hon 1/4 cua root thi tra ve khong
            else
            {
                if(Ob->getObjectRect().left >= root->_rect->left &&
                    Ob->getObjectRect().left < rectWidthNew &&
                    Ob->getObjectRect().top >= root->_rect->top &&
                    Ob->getObjectRect().top < rectHeightNew)//Left_Top
                    result =1;
                else 
                    if(Ob->getObjectRect().left < root->_rect->right &&
                        Ob->getObjectRect().left >= rectWidthNew &&
                        Ob->getObjectRect().top >= root->_rect->top &&
                        Ob->getObjectRect().top < rectHeightNew)//Right_Top
                        result =2;
                    else 
                        if(Ob->getObjectRect().left >= root->_rect->left &&
                            Ob->getObjectRect().left < rectWidthNew &&
                            Ob->getObjectRect().top >= rectHeightNew &&
                            Ob->getObjectRect().top < root->_rect->bottom)//Left_Bottom
                            result=3;
                        else//Right_Bottom
                            result=4;
            }

            if(result==0)//Add here
            {
                root->listObj.push_back(Ob);
                _count++; 
            }
            else
            {
                if(rectWidth/2 > LIM_W_H && rectHeight/2 > LIM_W_H)
                {
                    switch(result)
                    {
                    case 1://Left_Top
                        if(root->LT==NULL)
                            root->LT=new QuadNode(root->_rect->left,root->_rect->top,rectWidth/2,rectHeight/2);
                        Add(root->LT,Ob);
                        break;
                    case 2://Right_Top
                        if(root->RT==NULL)
                            root->RT=new QuadNode(rectWidthNew,root->_rect->top,rectWidth/2,rectHeight/2);
                        Add(root->RT,Ob);
                        break;
                    case 3://Left_Bottom
                        if(root->LB==NULL)
                            root->LB=new QuadNode(root->_rect->left,rectHeightNew,rectWidth/2,rectHeight/2);
                        Add(root->LB,Ob);
                        break;
                    case 4://Right_Bottom
                        if(root->RB==NULL)
                            root->RB=new QuadNode(rectWidthNew,rectHeightNew,rectWidth/2,rectHeight/2);
                        Add(root->RB,Ob);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    bool QuadTree::CheckPointInRECT(int x,int y,RECT rect)
    {
        if(x >= rect.left && x <= rect.right && y >= rect.top && y <= rect.bottom)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    bool QuadTree::CheckRECTInRECT(RECT r,RECT rect)
    {
        if(CheckPointInRECT(r.left,r.top,rect)
            ||CheckPointInRECT(r.right,r.top,rect)
            ||CheckPointInRECT(r.left,r.bottom,rect)
            ||CheckPointInRECT(r.right,r.bottom,rect)
            ||(rect.top<=r.top&&rect.bottom>=r.bottom&&r.left<=rect.left&&r.right>=rect.right))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    void QuadTree::GetObjInRec(QuadNode* root,RECT Screen,vector<Object*> &result)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<root->listObj.size();i++)
            if(CheckRECTInRECT(root->listObj[i]->getObjectRect(),Screen)||CheckRECTInRECT(Screen,root->listObj[i]->getObjectRect()))//active items on camera
            {
                result.push_back(root->listObj[i]);
            }
            if(root->LT!=NULL&&(CheckRECTInRECT(*root->LT->_rect,Screen)||CheckRECTInRECT(Screen,*root->LT->_rect)))
                GetObjInRec(root->LT,Screen,result);
            if(root->RT!=NULL&&(CheckRECTInRECT(*root->RT->_rect,Screen)||CheckRECTInRECT(Screen,*root->RT->_rect)))
                GetObjInRec(root->RT,Screen,result);
            if(root->LB!=NULL&&(CheckRECTInRECT(*root->LB->_rect,Screen)||CheckRECTInRECT(Screen,*root->LB->_rect)))
                GetObjInRec(root->LB,Screen,result);
            if(root->RB!=NULL&&(CheckRECTInRECT(*root->RB->_rect,Screen)||CheckRECTInRECT(Screen,*root->RB->_rect)))
                GetObjInRec(root->RB,Screen,result);
    }
    void QuadTree::DrawObjects(RECT Screen)
    {
        vector<Object*> total;
        this->GetAllObj(_pRoot,total);

        vector<Object*> result;
        //vector<Object*> allObjet;
        //GetAllObj(_pRoot,allObjet);
        GetObjInRec(_pRoot,Screen,result);
        for (int i=0; i<result.size();i++)
        {
            result[i]->draw(Screen);
        }
    }

//this function doesn't work
    void QuadTree::UpdatePosition(QuadNode *root,bool& OK)
    {
        //vector<Object*> okconde;
        //GetAllObj(_pRoot,okconde);

        if (root->LT == NULL && root->LB==NULL && root->RB==NULL && root->RT==NULL)
        {
            return;
        }
        vector<Object*>::iterator begin, end;
        begin=root->listObj.begin();
        end=root->listObj.end();

        while(begin!=end)
        {
            Object *Ob= *begin;

            if(Ob->getObjectType()!=1)
// get type of Object (if objectType !=1 so they are player or enemey which can move)
            {   


                if(Ob->IsMoving())
// these statement never reach- I have debuged.
                {
                    root->listObj.erase(begin);
                    this->Add(_pRoot,Ob);
                    OK=true;
                }
            }
            else
                begin++;
        }
        if(root->LT!=NULL)
            UpdatePosition(root->LT,OK);
        if(root->RT!=NULL)
            UpdatePosition(root->RT,OK);
        if(root->LB!=NULL)
            UpdatePosition(root->LB,OK);
        if(root->RB!=NULL)
            UpdatePosition(root->RB,OK);
    }

    QuadTree::~QuadTree(void)
    {
    }

    void QuadTree::GetAllObj(QuadNode *root,vector<Object*> &result)
    {

        for(int i=0;i<root->listObj.size();i++)
            result.push_back(root->listObj[i]);

        if(root->LT!=NULL)
            GetAllObj(root->LT,result);

        if(root->LB!=NULL)
            GetAllObj(root->LB,result);

        if(root->RT!=NULL)
            GetAllObj(root->RT,result);

        if(root->RB!=NULL)
            GetAllObj(root->RB,result);
    }

    void QuadTree::RemoveAll(QuadNode *root)
    {
        if (root!=NULL)
        {
            root->listObj.clear();
        }
        if (root->LB!=NULL)
            RemoveAll(root->LB);
        if (root->LT!=NULL)
            RemoveAll(root->LB);
        if (root->RB!=NULL)
            RemoveAll(root->LB);
        if (root->RT!=NULL)
            RemoveAll(root->LB);
    }
```

Comment: You really should tell us a bit more about your problems. It doesn't work is not a good error description. Where exactly does it fail, what happens and what do you expect to happen. Furthermore it's considered good practice to trim the code down to the minimal example which is enough too demonstrate the error, not many people will be willing to wade through all that code to find the error somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an exact answer but I have here a loose quadtree(it performs better than a quadtree yet still has the same structure) I have written.

```
    pastebin.com/e6yCLzNm
    Quadtree.h
    pastebin.com/REKBQmte
    Quadtree.cpp
```

That may help you.